# How to debug Java Web Start applications?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a Java Web Start Application that I launch from live site by downloading a tailored JNLP file.

The problem is that once the Java Web Start application has loaded, the application quits without any warning. I know that the certificate is OK since when I enable "Show site certificate from server even if it is valid" option from Java settings, it displays a message correspondigly.

I have tried enabling all debugging settings from Java settings ("Enable tracing", "Enable logging", "show applet lifecycle exceptions") and also Java console, but with no luck caching the problem.

Could anyone with more experience on Java Web Start development/debugging give any tips?

Comment: Did any of your own code get executed?

Comment: did the solution worked for you? which one option helped you? i am having the same problem, at client. The web start app freezes and shutdown. What did you do to fix the problem?

Comment: I did exactly what the answer said and it enabled me to debug my problem. Please, don't hesitate to open a new question if this didn't get you through your problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can launch a Web Start program form the command line using `javaws`, and pass JVM options with the `-J` flag.

Use a debugger to connect to that process:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/troubleshooting.03.06.html

Comment: javaws is only available in the jdk.  the jws app works fine for me but not for my boss who does not have jdk.  how to debug his version?

Comment: Have your boss install the jdk.